# java class calling rest api after 2 - 3 minutes continously

Tags: java, multithreading

I have one servlet class that is hitting a url exposed via rest. I have to call it continuously at a interval of 2 -3 minutes and keeping the response in a stack. I think, I have to do this with the help of thread mechanism.
What is best way to do this?

Comment: Please edit your post and show your work. What have you tried?  What research have your done?

Answer (score 1):

One option is use TimerTask: [Timer shedule](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date%29)

> TimerTask -- A task that can be scheduled for one-time or repeated execution by a Timer

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You could use a **[timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)**. Simply extend [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) and pass it to the Timer. If you want the task to start at application start up you can write a ServletContextListener to schedule the task.